# How to make the transaction slower for the sidebar and the jquery click only for once

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a push sidebar with Jquery onclick event and with the sidebar toggle the main body width will differ.This is what i have done so far.

```js
$(".for-sidebar").click(function(){
    $(".sidebar-container").css({
     'right' : '0px',
     'transition' : 'opacity 1s ease-in-out'
    });
    $(".body-container").css("width","-=300px");
});
$(".sidebar-close").click(function(){
    $(".sidebar-container").css({
     'right' : '-300px',
     'transition' : 'opacity 1s ease-in-out'
    });
    $(".body-container").css("width","100%");
});
```

```css
  html,body{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  .container{
   width: 100%;
  }
  .body-container{
   width: 100%;
  }
  .sidebar-container{
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   right: -300px;
   background: #000;
   color:#fff;
   height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Push Sidebar</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container">
     <div class="body-container">
           <h1>Hello, I am the body</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
           <button class="for-sidebar">open sidebar</button>
     </div>
     <div class="sidebar-container">
              <h1>Hello, I am the sidebar</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
            <button class="sidebar-close">close sidebar</button>
     </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want open sidebar click event to occur only once and the sidebar toggle slower.

Comment: So you mean `open` side bar once.. and even if they close it they cant open it again.. right?

Comment: No, i want the second time "open sidebar" is clicked, it won't change the body size as you can check in above code it is changing every time i click open sidebar

Comment: Ya I see.. let me give my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to have a smooth effect on the sidebar while pulling it in and out of the body.

Also I recommend you to hide the button `open sidebar` when ever the side bar is opened. So that user don't get a chance to click it at all.

Here is a working code.

```js
$(".for-sidebar").click(function(){
    $(".sidebar-container").animate({"right":"0px"}, "slow");
    $(".body-container").css("width","-=300px");
    $(this).hide(); // hide on first click
});
$(".sidebar-close").click(function(){
    $(".sidebar-container").animate({"right":"-300px"}, "slow");
    $(".body-container").css("width","100%");
    $(".for-sidebar").show(); // show when side bar is closed
});
```

```css
html,body{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  .container{
   width: 100%;
  }
  .body-container{
   width: 100%;
  }
  .sidebar-container{
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   right: -300px;
   background: #000;
   color:#fff;
   height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Push Sidebar</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container">
     <div class="body-container">
           <h1>Hello, I am the body</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
           <button class="for-sidebar">open sidebar</button>
     </div>
     <div class="sidebar-container">
              <h1>Hello, I am the sidebar</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
            <button class="sidebar-close">close sidebar</button>
     </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you :)

Comment: @BaladityaPanda glad to help